# PHP - Google Analytics - get pageviews of last previous hour

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics Client Api(https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git) to get the pageviews. It worked when I tried to get data from 7daysAgo to today, my code is:

```
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '7daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:visits',
        array(
            'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/project_z2o/',
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
            'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
            'max-results' => '25'
        ));
     }
```

but now, I want to get the data of the last previous hour. 
ex: current time is: *01-15-2016 11:49:50* and I run my code. I want to get the pageviews between *01-15-2016 **10:49:50*** and *01-15-2016 **11:49:50***.
How can I get it. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot usually get the last hour, since GA need some time to process hits (in the docs given as 4-24 hours, although on small sites processing sometimes seems almost instantly).

You can however get a limited set of information (pageviews, events, traffic sources, location, goal conversions) via [the Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) which might be better suited for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help..!